# Spring Boot application to put two host(having different port and url) against single datasource

Tags: spring-boot

Consider an Spring Boot application which connecting to single database having two nodes. Let’s call them Primary (P) and Secondary(S) nodes. Both P & S have different HOST(URL and port) details. When P goes down then S will up and running and vice versa. P & S both the nodes always in sync and data replicated on each other which we should not bother about.

Now the limitation is we only have to configure one data source in our spring application. IBM suggest that there is driver level affinity setup which help us to put multiple host details against one data source only. Below is the link which might help :
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tdat_clientaffinity.html

Bottom-line is we are trying to achieve this using Spring Boot to put multiple host details against one data source only. In case of failure from one host it should switch to next host.

Limitation : i don't want to create multiple datasource connection.

Comment: You should probably search for a solution on your database end. This is not a problem that your application needs or should worry about. What is your DB engine ?

Comment: IBM DB2, Are you sure that this is not achievable in spring boot. I have a reference link for mysql connector to illustrate this kind of scenario  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html